# How to merge different csv files(The headings are not exactly the same) in a folder into a single csv file in R

Tags: r, merge

My folder contains 365 csv files, which represent the air monitoring sites data for each day.I want to merge the different csv files into a single csv file in R.The problem is that the number of sites per CSV may be different, as new sites will be added over time.But I have a csv file named "total_sites" that contains all the sites at the end of the year.I want to use this "total_sites" to supplement the missing sites in each file so that the number of columns in each csv file will be the same, so I can use `rbind`and`do.call` to merge all the files together. But I do not know how to use the "total_sites" to supplement the missing sites in each file to make the number of columns in each file is the same .

the example of the files are as follows:
`file20170101`

```
#   date         A101   A102   A201   A202   A301 
#1  0101  PM2.5   1       1      1      1      1
#2  0101  SO2     1       1      1      1      2
#3  0101  NO2     2       2      2      2      2
```

`file20170810`

```
#   date       A101   A102   A201   A202   A301   A311  A312 A333 
#1  0810 PM2.5   1       1      1      1      1      1     1   1
#2  0810 SO2     1       1      1      1      2      2     2   2
#3  0810 NO2     2       2      2      2      2      3     3   3
```

`file20171010`

```
#   date       A101   A102   A201   A202   A301   A311  A312  A333  A334  A335 
#1  1010 PM2.5   1       1      1      1      1      1     1    1     1     1
#2  1010 SO2     1       1      1      1      2      2     2    2     2     2
#3  1010 NO2     2       2      2      2      2      3     3    3     2     2
```

`total_sites`

```
#         A101   A102   A201   A202   A301   A311  A312  A333  A334  A335 A400
```

the result I want is :

```
#    date        A101   A102   A201   A202   A301   A311  A312  A333  A334  A335 A400
#1  0101  PM2.5   1       1      1      1      1     NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA
#2  0101  SO2     1       1      1      1      2     NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA
#3  0101  NO2     2       2      2      2      2     NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA
#4  0810 PM2.5    1       1      1      1      1      1     1    1     NA   NA    NA
#5  0810 SO2      1       1      1      1      2      2     2    2     NA   NA    NA
#6  0810 NO2      2       2      2      2      2      3     3    3     NA   NA    NA
#7  1010 PM2.5    1       1      1      1      1      1     1    1     1     1    NA
#8  1010 SO2      1       1      1      1      2      2     2    2     2     2    NA 
#9  1010 NO2      2       2      2      2      2      3     3    3     2     2    NA
```

Answer (score 2):

We can load them into a `list` and use `bind_rows`.  It would fill the missing columns with `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
mget(ls(pattern = "^file\\d+$"))) %>%
      bind_rows
```

Answer (score 0):

To give an answer with data.table:

```
library(data.table)

#Detect all files in the folder:
filesList <- list.files("path/to/your/folder/",
           pattern = ".csv$",
           full.names = TRUE)

#Read in all files as data.table
tableList <- lapply(filesList, function(x) fread(x))

#Combine all data.tables in the list into one data.table and fill missing values
fullTable <- rbindlist(tableList, fill = TRUE)
```

However, keep in mind a minor limitation to this approach:

This only fills columns with NAs which are atleast present in one of the files. So if for example you would only merge 10 out of all CSVs you would only receive the columns which are present in atleast one of the files.

You can later write out the table in a single file with:

```
fwrite(fullTable, file = "path/to/somewhere/completeFile.csv")
```